# How to avoid problems in modelchecking if we don't allow any $q_f \in F$?

Tags: model-theory, formal-languages, automata

**We get** a specification $\varphi \in \mathsf{LTL}$ and we translate a real system to some NFA $A$.

**The problem** is to construct an NFA $A'$ with $L(A) = L(\neg \varphi)$, so we can check for $L(A') \cap L(A) = \emptyset$

**Question:** When translating a real system, which shouldn't end (i.e like an OS), to a NFA $(Q, \Sigma, \delta, I, F)$, we need to avoid final states $q_f \in F$. But when doing this, we get $L(A) = \emptyset$ since we never accept anything? So how can we avoid this in modelchecking?

Comment: You need a deterministic automaton to deal with the complement of a regular language.

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem since we can always convert NFA to DFA?

Comment: Of course, but the cost might be an exponential blow-up in the number of states.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my understanding, this problem can be resolved by making every state a final state.
This means, there are no special final states and still, words can be accepted. The steps of a path in the automaton correspond to time steps and when every state is a final one, the 'word' is accepted in every time step, meaning that is is still a valid system.